"Qneat3GeometryException: Dataset has wrong geometry type" error when running QNEAT3 Iso-Area as Polygons (from Layer) on QGIS
I got the following problem after executing the QNEAT3 on QGIS 3.38. How can I resolve it?
[QNEAT3Algorithm] This is a QNEAT3 Algorithm: 'Iso-Area as Polygons (from Layer)'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\IsoAreaAsPolygonsFromLayer.py", line 225, in processAlgorithm
input_coordinates = getListOfPoints(startPoints)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Utilities.py", line 95, in getListOfPoints
raise Qneat3GeometryException(given_geom_type, QgsWkbTypes().Point)
QNEAT3.Qneat3Exceptions.Qneat3GeometryException: Dataset has wrong geometry type. Got 1001 dataset but expected 1 dataset instead. 

Execution failed after 0.02 seconds

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_dfQFYg/ff990c65314640a088bf308080d699f7/OUTPUT_INTERPOLATION.tif


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
